# Switching from support-lib-v7-appcompat to actionbarsherlock lib in existing project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-support-library

I want to ask, if is there some way how to change support-library-v7-appcompat to actionbarsherlock lib in **existing project**. I've tried it many times and ways and I still get the same error - it removes all R.java folders and shows: Jar mismatch - fix your dependencies! I've already tried to put actionbarsherlock lib to new project and it works well. It only doesnt work, when I want to switch from another support-lib.

Do you have any idea, how to solve this problem?

Thank you very much

**By the way:**

I am doing it because it seems that appcompat doesnt support SearchView for API 7 but sherlock does - from what I read. Second think is, that my application project which has to be supported by sherlock is copy of another one. - I dont know, if it is important for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've solved it this way:

- I've created new project and added support library `ActionBarSherlock`
- A copied all of previous project to current - using Sherlock
- I put the same package to second project
- And of course I had to change some things in classes (`Fragment` to `SherlockFragment` etc.)